# How do I call a method?

Tags: java

I've done some searching on the Internet and I haven't had any luck, I know this is a simple thing but for the life of me I can't remember it (since I haven't done coding for about 2-3 months now) but today I decided to brush up on it and this is what I have:

```
public class Combat {
    public static void Fight() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
    }
}
```

Can someone help me what that line of code is that will go from `main(String[] args){` to `public static void Fight(){`?

Comment: `Fight();` I think this is what you want.

Comment: call Fight() inside main

Comment: I have changed you title to better reflect what was actually being asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call it by name followed by brackets:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Fight();
}
```

Note that by convention, method names start with a lowercase letter, so prefer naming the method `fight()` rather than `Fight()`.

Names that start with a capital are conventionally reserved for classes.

Answer (score 2):

Just call `Fight()` inside your main method.

In Java, you call a function using the function's name; if it has any parameters, those are inserted in the correct order using the expected types.

For instance,

```
public void Fight(String fighter){
//...
}
```

Would be called as `Fight("Thor")`.

I'd also suggest you take a look at the massive [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html), where you can get ontop of the basics or dive into some deeper aspects of the language.